# ASP.Net C# Setting up separate Mvc and WebApi projects to use the same database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hey there I am stuck on the following problem:

I have a solution which contains the following projects:

- ~.Api
- ~.Mvc
- ~.Data
  Where the ~.Api projects contains Api Controllers to communicate with the Database, the ~.Data project which contains all the models and repositories and a class derived from DbContext and finally an ~.MVC project which contains MVCs.

Now the issue at hand is the fact that they need to be using the same Database, However when I give both projects the same  and  tags in their respective Web.config files the first projects that tries to call the database works fine, but the other one gets an error(the same as below).

I also tried deleting the tags from both files and giving the Class that is derived from DbContext a : base("connectionstring" with it's constructor. This resulted in an error "~.Mvc\App_Data\connectionstring.mdf' as database 'connectionstring'".

I'm thinking it might be an issue where the second project wants to create it's own version of the Database but it already exists, but it could also be something totally different.

Has anyone had a similar problem or do you know what I should do? All help is appreciated!

Comment: That error message makes no sense - is that the full message? I suspect, since you appear to be using .mdf databases which are just files on disk, the projects need to be able to reference the actual path of the DB. If you specify "app_data" as the path in each project, that refers to a folder _within that project_. Or better still, IMHO, use a proper database that runs as a service, where you access it via ports rather than a file reference. SQL Server Community edition is free to install. Then it's easy to connect to it from any project using the same connection string.

Comment: Completely agree with ADyson's point. You need to have an SQL instance rather than a `mdf` file. The benefit of SQL is that you can consume it from as many projects as you wish unlike mdf.

Comment: Can I do this using MSSQLLocalDb?
Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed the reference to the mdf file, I usually do without one but I think that part was generated and I didn't think to check it. 

Thanks a lot @ADyson and ViVi for making me look at it!

I just removed this part from the connectionstring "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SchoolManagementSystem.Mvc-20170526013041.mdf"

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a static method that returns an instance of the database context from your data layer?
Then, you can refer to your data layer from the api and the mvc projects, and just call the static method.

I think you should create a business layer that refer to the data layer and then you can call the buisness logic from your api and the MVC projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, I did have that method as static, I made an oopsie in the connection string. I Found it thanks to @ViVi and ADyson